# Creating a Bitcoin brain-wallet using an Ethereum contract

Tags: contract-development, addresses, bitcoin

I would like to create a Bitcoin brain-wallet generator using an Ethereum contract that takes as input a given password, and gives as output a deterministic Bitcoin private and public key corresponding to the given password. I assume the deriving of the addresses themselves from the password could be done purely by hashfunctions (SHA-256 and RIPEMD160). The motivation is of course to have an "indestructible" and trustless brain-wallet such that the generator can never be lost, and one would know for sure that it does not store any generated keys. Is this possible, and how do I ensure that the function input is not exposed to the network and/or "man in the middle attacks"? thanks.

Comment: If the function that accepts the password and gives the private/public key pair as output is a constant function, i.e. it does not write anything to storage and does not change the blockchain state, then calling it would not send a transaction to the blockchain. The function would just run locally on the node, so I think that the password will not be exposed to the network. Also, if it can be called as a constant function, that would give the user confidence that the contract is not storing the generated private key in its storage.

Comment: I did not make my previous comment an answer because I would like someone with more expertise and knowledge to confirm that I am correct.

Comment: @AjoyBhatia  Makes sense, I am pretty sure you are right.

Comment: I will convert it to an answer, and let someone else who knows more post their own answer, if needed.

Comment: @AjoyBhatia I agree with your interpretation. Nifty idea.

Comment: @AjoyBhatia Yeah, also good point about the transparency, coming to think of it, the transparency would also make it trustless. The current hosted generators could easily store the private key if the wanted to :)

Comment: Sorry to say, but it doesn't look like a secure way to generate a key. To securely derive a key you normaly use key derivation function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function PBKDF2 is an standard used frequently. But to generate a good Ethereum/Bitcoin private key you need a pretty good random source.

Comment: In response to @Ismael's comment - my comment was not addressing the validity of how the key pair is generated. It was only addressing Daniel's original question about how to not expose the input password to the network. I see that Daniel has **edited out** that part from the question now. Also, the original question did not say anything about a user calling the function suspecting that the contract might be storing the private key. That angle was my addition but Daniel has **added** that to his question now.

Comment: @AjoyBhatia True, I edited it out in fear of asking the obvious, but I can add it back in, as there was some interesting points made about it now.

Comment: You could add it back if you want. I was not blaming you but just felt that the context in which I had answered was lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function that accepts the password and gives the private/public key pair as output is a constant function, i.e. it does not write anything to storage and does not change the blockchain state, then calling it would not send a transaction to the blockchain. The function would just run locally on the node, so I think that the password will not be exposed to the network. Also, if it can be called as a constant function, that would give the user confidence that the contract is not storing the generated private key in its storage.

Comment: I want to emphasize that the caller should send the function call to a **local node**. If the call is made over JSON-RPC API to a remote node, then a password sent in plaintext could be sniffed in the HTTP traffic on the Internet.